# TRRS 3.5 mm Audio Plug (male) into a printed circuit board

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, breadboard, headphones, stereo

Have a device I'd like to plug into a headphone jack of a cell phone. Wanted to start making some more professional prototypes; print my first circuit boards, etc.

I'd like to be able to implement a male headphone plug like this into my PCB: [image]

Note that this is male.

Notice how the places to solder are super fricken tiny. What's the best way for me to connect this to a circuit board with the least amount of effort? I don't have the manual dexterity to solder DIP pins onto these areas in a quick and efficient manner (do I need a better soldering iron?).

Or is there an SMT way to do things (I don't see how there could be given the barreled nature of these components)?

Lastly, maybe there is a breakout of some kind for these somewhere out there? I can't find any.

Comment: That particular plug is not intended to be soldered to a PCB. You'd have much more luck with something like [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tensility-international-corp/54-00035/839-1239-ND/5609420)

Comment: You rock!!!!!!!!!!! Can I ask how you found this? What filter was I missing in my DigiKey search?

Comment: Btw, I have been at this for months thinking there was no other way.

Comment: "Mounting Type: Through Hole, Right Angle" might have been the key specification.